# How to fix attribute 'list'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have some qeustion and problem with celaning text on my NLP model. I dont know why i get this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split.
On below is my `df['Text'].sample(5)` :

```
26278    [RT, @davidsirota:, subset, people, website, t...
63243    [RT, @jmartNYT:, The, presses, Team, Biden, As...
61059    [RT, @caitoz:, BREAKING:, Biden, nominate, "Li...
43160    [RT, @K_JeanPierre:, I, profoundly, honored, P...
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

On below is my code

```
def tokenizer(text):
    
    tokenized = [w for w in text.split() if w not in stopset]
    return tokenized
df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(tokenizer)
def remove_emoji(string):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                           u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                           u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                           u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                           u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', string)
def remove_nonwords(Text):
    if re.findall('\d',Text):
        return ''
    else:
        return Text
def clean_text(Text):
    text=' '.join([i for  i in Text.split() if i not in stopset])
    text=' '.join([stem.stem(word) for word in Text.split()])
    return Text
df['text2'] = df['Text'].apply(clean_text)
```

Could you someone help me ?

Comment: It seems `df['Text']` contains list, so you can't call split() on its elements. Try `text=' '.join([i for  i in Text if i not in stopset])`

Comment: I got now AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I have laso on another cells def tokenizer(Text):
    
    tokenized = [w for w in Text.split() if w not in stopset]
    return tokenized

Comment: check out this -  https://www.kaggle.com/ragnisah/text-data-cleaning-tweets-analysis

Comment: Do you understand the problem I pointed in my first comment ? If so, you'll understand how to solve your problem

Comment: Hey guys i will resolve problem usinng another loop. Thanks